# Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80070006) Aplication Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

## Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80070006)

Recently my application insights thrown strange exception:

`Merging of ETL files has failed (0x80070006). Problem Id:System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException at DiagnosticsHub.StandardCollector.Host.Interop.ICollectionSession.Stop`

When I change configuration:
APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION to `disabled`
The exception gone. But when I change to `1.0.0` as [ms document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/profiler/profiler-azure-functions#app-settings-for-enabling-profiler),it ' back.

I just want to remove exception safely. Thanks

I have change app service configuration.
It's work if setting:
APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION = disable

But I don't know why and what it will impact

Answer (score 1):

- When the configuration `APPINSIGHTS_PROFILERFEATURE_VERSION` to "disabled," the exception is resolved because the profiler feature is turned off.
- I have tried as you did by creating a function app and configured an application Insight to it.

[image]

- The exception is related to the merging of ETL (Event Tracing for Windows) files in the application insights. The error code "0x80070006" typically indicates a "handle is invalid" error.
- To remove the exception safely and utilize the profiler feature. Verify that the account running the application has the necessary permissions to access and merge the ETL files. Additionally, ensure that any required dependencies for ETL merging are properly installed.

[image]

- There should be no other applications or services running on the same machine that may interfere with the ETL file merging process.